# How to parse a jsonify object in python and display in html?

Tags: python, jquery, json, ajax, flask

I have a flask app that returns the output from a jsonify function but the output that is displayed on the html is not pretty. I now to parse this output and modify it before returning it to the html. I tried to iterate over the json output but it doesn't let me do that. How do I do that?

First here is the output from the jsonify function on my webpage

> Prediction: Apple Cedar rust,99.6459424495697,Bell_Pepper
>   healthy,0.2868120325729251,Blueberry healthy,0.05757397739216685

I want something like this

> **Predictions**:
>
> Apple Cedar rust: 99.6459424495697
>
> Bell_Pepper healthy: 0.2868120325729251
>
> Blueberry healthy: 0.05757397739216685

Now here is the code for the same in my app.py file

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the file from post request
        f = request.files['file']

        # Save the file to ./uploads
        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        file_path = os.path.join(
            basepath, 'uploads', secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.save(file_path)

        result = model_predict(file_path, model)
        return jsonify(result)

    return None
```

Finally here is the code for my main.js file

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/predict',
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        // Get and display the result
        $('.loader').hide();
        $('#result').fadeIn(600);
        $('#result').text(' Prediction:  ' + data);
        console.log('Success!');
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `result` from `result = model_predict(file_path, model)`?

Comment: I already posted it in my question above. But anyway here it is `Prediction: Apple Cedar rust,99.6459424495697,Bell_Pepper healthy,0.2868120325729251,Blueberry healthy,0.05757397739216685`. Here is the github repo for the app.py script https://github.com/upendrak/Disease_Predictor/blob/master/app.py. Here is the link to the output image - https://i.postimg.cc/L5pzK29m/final-image.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an HTML string which can be utilized as the body of the `#result` div:

In your `app.py`, in `upload`:

```
...
result = model_predict(file_path, model)
return flask.jsonify({'html':'\n'.join(f'<p>{a}: {b}</p>' for a, b in result)})
```

In `main.js`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/predict',
  data: form_data,
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  async: true,
  success: function (data) {
    // Get and display the result
    $('.loader').hide();
    $('#result').fadeIn(600);
    $('#result').append(data.html); //add previously formatted html to div
    console.log('Success!');
   },
});
```

---

Javascript rendering of values:

In `app.py`:

```
import json
result = model_predict(file_path, model)
return flask.jsonify({'payload':json.dumps([{'name':a, 'val':b} for a, b in result])})
```

In `main.js`:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: '/predict',
 data: form_data,
 contentType: false,
 cache: false,
 processData: false,
 async: true,
 success: function (data) {
    // Get and display the result
   $('.loader').hide();
   $('#result').fadeIn(600);
   var new_data = JSON.parse(data.payload);
   $('#result').append('Prediction: ');
   for (var i in new_data){
     var _html = `
       <p>${new_data[i].name}: ${new_data[i].val}</p>
     `
      $('#result').append(_html);
   }
   console.log('Success!');
  },
});
```

Comment: I tried incorporating the first line (`result = re.sub('^Prediction:', '', model_predict(file_path, model)).split(',')`) to start with in my app.py file but I got an error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`.

Comment: @upendra Can you clarify what type `result` is? Can you put a `print(result)` call below `result = model_predict(file_path, model)` and post the result?

Comment: Here it is Type is `<class 'list'>`
Result output is ```[('Apple Cedar rust', 99.6459424495697), ('Bell_Pepper healthy', 0.2868120325729251), ('Blueberry healthy', 0.05757397739216685), ('Raspberry healthy', 0.006377929094014689), ('Cherry(Sour) healthy', 0.0007768640898575541)]```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to anything apart from the above two files (app.py and main.js)? I am not getting the result back. I'm just getting this `Prediction: [object Object]`

Comment: @upendra The code above is all you need to change. Simply return `flask.jsonify({'html':'\n'.join(f'<p>{a}: {b}</p>' for a, b in result)})` from `upload` in `app.py` and put `$('#result').append(data.html)` in the `success` handler of the `ajax`. Make sure you are using `data.html`, not `data`, as the latter is the object (which would explain `[object Object]`), while the former is the desired HTML string result. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195162/discussion-between-upendra-and-ajax1234).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `result` is a valid json object passed into `jasonify(result)`, you would need to iterate through the data object in your `main.js` and display the `key:value` pairs programmatically.
Something like this:

```
// data =  { 'Apple Cedar rust': '99.6459424495697', ...  }
$.each(data,function(key,value){
   $('#results-list').append("<span>"+ key +": " + value + "</span>")
});
```